# compile threadscope (0.2.2) with current gtk2hs (0.12.5)

Tags: haskell

Threadscope does not have sharp version bounds in its cabal file, and it seems that some exports changed in gtk2hs after the last threadscope release. I needed the following trivial changes to compile threadscope-0.2.2 (current from hackage) with gtk-0.12.5.6 (current from hackage):

```
diff -r threadscope-0.2.2/GUI/SaveAs.hs threadscope-0.2.2.1/GUI/SaveAs.hs
12c12
< import Graphics.Rendering.Cairo
---
> import Graphics.Rendering.Cairo hiding ( height, width, Region )
diff -r threadscope-0.2.2/GUI/Timeline/Render.hs threadscope-0.2.2.1/GUI/Timeline/Render.hs
24c24
< import Graphics.Rendering.Cairo
---
> import Graphics.Rendering.Cairo hiding ( height, width, Region )
diff -r threadscope-0.2.2/GUI/Timeline.hs threadscope-0.2.2.1/GUI/Timeline.hs
37c37
< import Graphics.Rendering.Cairo
---
> import Graphics.Rendering.Cairo hiding ( height, width, Region )
diff -r threadscope-0.2.2/threadscope.cabal threadscope-0.2.2.1/threadscope.cabal
2c2
< Version:             0.2.2
---
> Version:             0.2.2.1
```

NB: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/ThreadScope#Development_and_reporting_bugs points to http://trac.haskell.org/ThreadScope/ which points back. Hm.

Comment: I don't see a question. If the question is how to open a ticket, just create an account and open a ticket on the second link you gave.

Comment: ThreadScope 0.2.3. compiles fine with this version of gtk.